# Ubuntu 20.04, on-screen keyboard not showing when using touchscreen on LENOVO YOGA 500

Tags: keyboard, lenovo, touchscreen, 20.04, onscreen-keyboard

Well, the title says it. I have a Lenovo yoga 500, recently updated to 20.04. When I was on 19.10, the keyboard used to show automatically when I touch a textbox. However, now it won't open, unless I do it manually via the Universal Access menu. I'll be happy If someone can help me.

Comment: Same here on an Eve V. Initial install was 18.10. The on-screen keyboard would open reliably when touching any text entry field. This stopped working after upgrading from 19.10 to 20.04.

Additionally swiping up from the bottom to force the on-screen keyboard to show up no longer works either.

Comment: Same issue, I have an HP Pavilion 15z. I had 18.04 initially where onscreen keyboard worked when tapping text inputs. Then did a clean install of 20.04 a couple weeks ago and tapping no longer works, unless activating through settings BUT that brings up the onscreen keyboard with non-touch selection.

Comment: Same problem with Yoga X390: was working like a charm in 19.10, does not work in 20.04 LTS :(

Comment: @Gecko Thanks for mentioning swiping from the bottom up, this actually brings up the keyboard for me on Ubuntu 20.04

Answer (score 0):

Logout and switch to Ubuntu(Xorg) session. That fixed both keyboard and rotation problems for me in Ubuntu 21

Answer (score -2):

You need to turn it on under the accessibility options.  Here's [the official documentation](https://help.ubuntu.com/stable/ubuntu-help/keyboard-osk.html.en).  It appears to pop up all the time now though.

1. Open the **Activities** overview and start typing "Settings".
2. Click on **Settings**.
3. Click **Universal Access** in the sidebar to open the panel.
4. Switch on **Screen Keyboard** in the **Typing** section.

Comment: Yes, I know, I said the same in my post. I want it to show automatically when I touch a textbox and not to show when I click it, as it was in 19.10. If I turn it on manually via the universal access menu, it would show everytime, no matter if a textbox is touched or clicked.

Comment: is there a way, i can bring it up any time i want instead of it popping up by iteself for inputs. i would like to use it for vlc media player to use hot keys.

Comment: As a workaround, in the Universal Access menu you can check the "Always Show Universal Access menu", which will add a dropdown menu to the top bar to quickly set/unset the OSK. If you have a laptop that can switch into tablet mode like me, this is a reasonable solution (it would be nicer if it could switch into OSK mode automatically when folding the screen back, of course).